# Undefined reference to "SteamAPI_INIT"

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Всем привет! На моем компьютере установлена Ubuntu 19.04 x64. В проекте Qt в qt Creator я пытался подключить "libsteam_api.so" (так было сказано на сайте API STEAMWORKS), [image: сайт стим] но при компиляции опять ошибка [image: error]. Вот часть код файла .pro:

```
QT       += core gui
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/public/steam/
LIBS += -L"libsteam_api.so"
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```cpp
bool MainWindow::init()
{
    if (!SteamAPI_Init()) {
        myError("Couldn't init STEAMAPI!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

А вот файлы в каталоге проекта:
[image: каталог]

Comment: Разве в Linux'e динамические библиотеки имеют расширение .dll? LIBS += L"libsteam_api.so" вот так поидее)

Comment: исправил. но все равно ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключение `libsteam_api.so`:

```
LIBS += -L"<путь к папке с либой>" -lsteam_api
```

вместо префикса `lib` указывается `-l`. Расширение указывать не обязательно.

Либо так:

```
LIBS += -L"<путь к папке с либой>" libsteam_api.so
```

Если либа находится рядом с файлом pro, то путь можно не указывать:

```
LIBS += -lsteam_api
```

либо указать как `-L"./"`

```
LIBS += -L"./" -lsteam_api
```

в общем виде так:

```
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/путь/к/папке" -lsteam_api
```

здесь $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_ - путь к файлу pro проекта

Comment: а что уазывать в "<путь к папке с либой>". если файл находится в корне проекта? "/"?

Comment: попробуйте  `./`

Comment: Все равно не получается. Я вспомнил, что проект компилируется в отдельную папку build-QSam-Desktop_Qt_5_12_5_GCC_64bit-Debug. Может туда добавить либу?

Comment: нет, туда не надо. Попробуйте указать полный путь, или сделать как у меня указано в последней строчке (только что обновил)

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ БОЛЬШОЕ!